# How to download the Java Naming and Directory Interface documentation?

Tags: java, oracle, ftp, jndi, javadoc

I have a simple question, I want to download the Oracle's documentation on JNDI from the official website:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jndi/javadoc/

However when I click on the "JNDI API Document (PDF)" a window prompts asking:

The server ftp://ftp.javasoft.com:21 requires a username and password.

I tried both with my Oracle account password as well as with the combination anonymous/ as suggested on several websites... 
I get always the message "login incorrect"!

Any clues?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work, but Googling JNDI API PDF or something finds this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jndi-150206.pdf is that the document that you want?

Comment: Yes this is what I wanted! Thanks! Nevertheless I still wonder why it is not possible to download pdfs from the website I posted!

Comment: It's strange. Perhaps you could let Oracle know about it but I doubt they would do anything about it anyway :) ... Btw: I posted the solution from my comment as an answer so you can mark it as accepted if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you can't download it from the link mentioned in JavaDocs, but here is an alternative [download link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jndi-150206.pdf) which works.